# Android manifest not updating app version from Gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

Based on [this Google document](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) I'm expecting Gradle to update my manifest.xml file with a version number, notably this quoted section:

```
The defaultConfig element configures core settings and entries in the manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) dynamically from the build system. The values in defaultConfig override those in the manifest file.
```

However when I change the version code or version name of my Gradle file, the values arent' changed in my manifest.

- Is this normal behavior?
- Which values, between the manifest and the gradle build, are stting version codes and names?
- How can I make the connection between the manifest versions and the gradle build more visible?

Answer (score 2):

Even I am facing the similar issue. It is the default behaviour of gradle system I guess. You need to update both `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle` seperately if there is any changes in sdk versions, version code, version name,etc. I am looking forward that these kinda issues must be fixed in upcoming releases.

Answer (score 2):

I have versionCode(1.0.3) and versionName(8) in my build.gradle only and it had worked correctly for me in past.

Now I updated the versionCode to 1.0.4 and versionName to 1 but it kept on giving me error on Google play. I even tried adding the new versionCode and versionName to AndroidManifest.xml but it did not help. Only thing that worked was updating the versionName to a higher number (9). Something seems broken in the Google Play upload apk and verify mechanism. Hopefully my answer would save someone else's 1 hour for solving this silly bug.